# Does stream().groupingBy maintain sorted order for the resulting map value lists?

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I have an ArrayList which I stream, then sort, then group by some attribute of the list values. Will the lists in the resulting map be internally sorted (i.e. maintain the ordering of the stream before it was grouped)?

In the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) it says groupingBy is not an unordered collector but I wasn't sure if the above is what that means. If not, what does ordered/unordered collector mean?

```
    arrayList.stream()
        .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o->o.getAttribute())
```

When I tried this gave me ordered lists but I need to be able to guarantee it will always result in ordered lists and wasn't sure if it would break with different input or when using multiple threads etc.

Comment: Very interesting point. The Javadocs say nothing about it. But the stream, being not parallel, processes the items of the ordered list one-by-one. Then it puts them in the corresponding bucket which is a list too. It is reasonable to assume order is preserved. But, since it is not specified in contract, I would prefer to group-by first, and then sort the resulting lists individually.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos the map used is probably a `HashMap`, which definitely does *not* preserve insertion order.

Comment: @RobSpoor I should clarify, the values in this map are themselves lists, and I am referring to the internal ordering of those lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`groupingBy(function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) collector is a short-hand for `groupingBy(function, toList())`. While there are no guarantees about the order of the map entries, the lists collected by `toList()` will reflect the encounter order.

While it is not spelled out explicitly, how the `groupingBy` collector affects the operation of the downstream collector regarding the order, there is a remark in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) about the difference to `groupingByConcurrent(Function)`:

> For parallel stream pipelines, the `combiner` function operates by merging the keys from one map into another, which can be an expensive operation. If preservation of the order in which elements appear in the resulting `Map` collector is not required, using `groupingByConcurrent(Function)` may offer better parallel performance.

This hints at the fact that the `groupingBy` collector will preserve the order if the downstream collector is not *unordered*, whereas the `groupingByConcurrent` collector will enforce *unordered* behavior, even if the downstream collector would otherwise retain the order, like `toList()`.

So the following program

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(isUnordered(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())));
  System.out.println(isUnordered(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(Function.identity())));
}
static boolean isUnordered(Collector<?, ?, ?> c) {
  return c.characteristics().contains(Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
```

will print

```
false
true
```

---

As a reminder to those who didn’t read carefully enough, we’re only talking about the order of the elements within the lists, not the order of the entries within the map.

So when we take the following program, for example

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> m = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i % 2));

System.out.println(m.keySet());
System.out.println(m.get(0));
System.out.println(m.get(1));
```

There is no guaranty whether the first line will be `[0, 1]` or `[1, 0]`, as the map’s order is unspecified, but we can be sure that the other two lines will be

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

as the lists have a guaranteed order and `m.get(0)`/`m.get(1)` do not rely on the map’s order.