# Java iterate list of objects and add to map of map

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an employee table like below,

```
id | name | department | sub_department |
-----------------------------------------
1  | emp1 | Finance    | finance_asia   | 
2  | emp2 | Finance    | finance_emea   |
3  | emp3 | Retail     | retail_us      |
4  | emp4 | Investment | inv_africa     |
5  | emp5 | Investment | inv_aus        |
```

I have a spring boot project which gets data from above table using JPA repository,

```
List<Employee> empList = empRepo.findAll();
```

Employee class has id, name, department and sub_department of type String.

Now I need to create a Map<department, Map<sub_department, List>>.
I am able to achieve using below code,

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Employee>>> departmentMap = new HashMap<>();
var empList = empRepo.findAll();
empList.stream().foreach(emp -> {
   if (departmentMap.get(emp.getDepartment()) == null) {
       departmentMap.put(emp.getDepartment(), new HashMap<String, List<Employee>>);
   }
   if (departmentMap.get(emp.getDepartment()).get(emp.getSubDepartment()) == null) {
       departmentMap.get(emp.getDepartment()).put(emp.getSubDepartment(), new ArrayList<Employee>);   
   }
   departmentMap.get(emp.getDepartment()).get(emp.getSubDepartment()).add(emp);
});
```

above code does the job. But it is more traditional or legacy approach. Is there any approach more efficient than this and can be achieved with less lines of code ?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Missed to add one thing. List should be based on name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
var empList = empRepo.findAll();
Map<String, Map<String, List<Employee>>> departmentMap = empList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Employee::getDepartment, 
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Employee::getSubDepartment, 
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/I0w2Lf)

Comment: can we also add sort to the List<Employee> based on name ?

Comment: @Lolly Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- Adding a `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName))` between `.stream()` and `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(` seems to do the trick. I am, however, not sure whether this guarantees the order.

Comment: I didn't tried, but maybe sorting empList at the beginning by name will do the trick

Comment: It seems that [`groupingBy(...)` preserves the order (`stackoverflow.com`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74476426/does-stream-groupingby-maintain-sorted-order-for-the-resulting-map-value-lists).